# Can I use spackling paste to "rebuild" part of the wall?

Tags: drywall, walls, tile, paint, spackling-paste

I'm on a DIY half bathroom renovation. At first I was thinking about putting tiles on the wall. It's a drywall, which I'm not familiar with, it's painted and I would need to do some preparations to install the tiles.

I decided to sand it, but turns out it seems to have to many patches / joints because I could reach the fiberglass tape in different areas of the wall. So instead of tiles we decided to just repair the wall and paint it.

(Please, advice me if there is any chance that we can install wall to it)

My question at this point is:

Can I use spackling paste to repair part of the wall where it's uneven?
It would be on this area where there are some holes as well.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joint compound (not "spacking paste") is designed for exactly that purpose. Your repair isn't that different from a typical taping job. One doesn't normally sand that much from a wall.

Use a large knife or trowel (12" or bigger) and taper it out at least that far.

Comment: It would be helpful to OP to understand why you included "(not "spackling paste")". I actually did not know there was a difference, so I just looked it up ("difference between joint compound and spackling"). "The main difference between them is that spackling paste resists shrinking and is formulated primarily for filling smaller holes." Apparently I've been using the wrong stuff.

Comment: There are any number of joint compounds. You might want to recommend one for this job. I think a tub of pre-mixed all purpose would be appropriate? As compared to hot mud.

Answer (score 0):

Applying tile to drywall in a wet environment is a bad idea.  Take a look at the bottom of that wall.  It looks like water already got to the edge.  If this is the part of the bathroom that is not by the tub or in the shower, you can tile it.

Tile surfaces have to be FLAT.  The less flat it is, the smaller the tile you use.

One of the downsides of tile is that grout collects crud.  The grout is hard to clean.  Sealing your grout helps.

Water gets spilled in the bathroom. End your wall 1/4" above the floor.  Cover the gap with baseboard.  This keeps water from wicking up in the wall.  If this has already happened, trim the wall board short.  If the board is falling apart, you may need to cut a strip off and replace.

There are various wall board products that may work:  One that is popular here is ceramalite.  Looks like 5 foot squares of tile or stone.  It is NOT water proof, especially on a cut edge.  The face is pretty good.  The factory edges tolerable.

This forum has some discussions on it.  https://www.renovateforum.com/f205/ceramalite-laminex-panels-shower-walls-32828/  Consensus:  It works, it's easy to install. More expensive than tile. Trim isn't up to snuff.